# Почему возникает ошибка при передаче char С++

Tags: c++, char

```
//пример перегрузки конструктора класса (сам класс)
    class timer {
        int seconds;
    public:
        timer(char* t) { seconds = atoi(t); }
        timer(int t) { seconds = t; }
        timer(int min, int sec) { seconds = min * 60 + sec; }
        void run();
    };
    
int main()
{
    timer a(10), b("20"), c(1, 10); //инициализация объектов класса
    return 0;
}
```

Ругается на b("20"). А если пишу вот так, то перестает ругаться:

```
int main()
{
char t[] = "20";
timer a(10), b(t), c(1, 10);
    return 0;
}
```

Почему ругается компилятор в первом случае? Объясните пожалуйста.

Comment: Вообще-то он ругается и так, и эдак - потому что вы объявили конструктор от `char`, а передаете туда строку. Вот, смотрите сами: https://ideone.com/5KigDS А вот если бы вы написали `timer(const char*)`, то он и в самом деле не ругался бы ни в первом, ни во втором случае... Так что где-то вы неправду пишете...

Comment: Простите, сначала вставил в шапку не тот кусок кода что хотел. Поменял. Посмотрите ещё раз пожалуйста.

Comment: `"20"` - это массив константный, а `char t[] = "20";`  - это новый массив **не** константых букв.

Comment: Как правильно написать передачу параметра 20 сразу в "timer(char* t);" без использования строки char t[] = "20"; ?

Comment: Добавьте `const`-квалификатор параметру в конструкторе. Вместо `timer(char* t)...` напишите `timer(const char* t)...`. Вам же первым комментарием написали про `const`...